# How to run main thread as a real time thread

Tags: java, real-time, real-time-java

In real time Java one can create a real time thread and run it via the following methods:

```
RealtimeThread rt = new RealtimeThread(){
    public void run(){
        /*do work*/
    }
};
rt.start();

RealtimeThread rt2 = new RealtimeThread();
rt2.start();

RealtimeThread rt3 = new RTThread();
rt3.start();
```

where RTThread is a class which extends RealtimeThread. But clearly the above approaches does not work when it comes to main. So is there a way to do it? My motivation for this is that I want only 2 real time threads to run. If I start two real time threads within main, won't there be a total of 3 threads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the `RealtimeThread`s are not deamon threads you can let the main thread finish and keep everything running inside the `RealtimeThread`s

```
public class BootStrap extends Runnable{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new RealtimeThread(new BootStrap()).start();
        //main finishes running and stops
    }

    public void run(){
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested, it works beautifully. I've also added a `sleep()`, then a `CyclicBarrier` before the actual code in `public void run()` to make sure main really dies and the other two threads start working at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

> ***If I start two real time threads within main, won't there be a total of 3 threads?***

No. If you start two threads, then return / "fall off the edge" of the main method, you'll have two threads running.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't *all* threads RealTimeThreads in RTJ? including the main thread?

Comment: That would be awesome, but I don't remember reading it anywhere. Also tested this with the following code:
`Thread currT = Thread.currentThread();
if(currT instanceof RealtimeThread) System.out.println("Yeah!");
else if(currT instanceof Thread) System.out.println("Meh.");
else System.out.println("WTF O.o");`

It printed "Meh."